# Android - Using Fragments

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I'm very new to Java, and Android development. I want to be able to display a local page page within my App using the fragments (because I don't want the entire app to be web based).

So, I've gone into my arview.xml and added a fragment:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_bbc"
        android:name="android.webkit.WebViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Now, I want to place a web page in there (for now, I'll just use the bbc website).

Within my 'onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)' I have this:

```
webFrag = (WebViewFragment) mGUIView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_bbc);
mWebView = (WebView) mGUIView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_bbc);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
```

I have errors of all 3 of those lines, all saying they can't be resolved.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Generally in fragment you use findviewbyid() in the onCreateView method, and then in the onviewCreated() you do some treatement.

Comment: what is this MGUIView? if it is your mainActivity, you won't need a reference for your current View.

Comment: MGUIView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.arview, null);

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the "tag" fragment in xml, just do a classic layout and use it in a Class that extend Fragment

Example :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved) {
        _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accueil, group, false);
        // get views
        _textViewTitle = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.title_home);
        _buttonLocalSearch = (Button) _view.findViewById(R.id.btn_local_search);
        return _view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    {
          _textViewTitle.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.tle_home));
          _buttonLocalSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you need to initialize the components you want to use and select the variable-type on your own. In your case try changing

```
webFrag = (WebViewFragment) mGUIView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_bbc);
mWebView = (WebView) mGUIView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_bbc);
```

to

```
WebViewFragment webFrag = (WebViewFragment) mGUIView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_bbc);
WebView mWebView = (WebView) mGUIView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_bbc);
```

---

or you do it entirely different and try something like this:

```
WebView wv =  new WebView();
wv.findViewById();
```

Comment: Thanks, when I do this, I get these errors: - WebViewFragment cannot be resolved to a 
  type
 - fragment_bbc cannot be resolved or is not a 
  field

Comment: Do I have to create a new Java Class? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you previously instantiate those variables?

Try:

```
WebViewFragment webFrag = (WebViewFragment) findViewById(R.id.fragment_bbc);
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_bbc);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
```

Comment: I get these errors: - fragment_bbc cannot be resolved or is not a 
  field
 - WebViewFragment cannot be resolved to a 
  type

Answer (score 0):

I thik your way of implementation is wrong.

First of all simply you have to do this

1. Add Fragment to your parent activity
2. Then using instance of your `WebViewFragment` call the method loadUrl()

And here is the [code for WebViewFragment](http://code.google.com/p/android-news-compatible/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/news/WebViewFragment.java?r=2) just supply your url to `loadUrl()` method thats it.

Please check that link that will guide you well.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to Java, I have no idea what you mean when you say 'add fragment to your parent activity' ?

Comment: Wait, do I have to create a new Java Class?

Comment: (Fragment basic)[http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html] this link guide for what is fragment is.

(and this example give answer what I mean for my fst point)[http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html]

Comment: So I do have to create a new Java Class? Can I not place it in my current class script?

Comment: In your project there will be one Activity class, on that class your showing your current fragment, so you dont have to create separate Java class modify your current activity according to standards Google had mentioned it there above doc.

Comment: How do I find out which my one my main activity class is? All my classes are custom named (I know when you start a new project, you get a class called 'MainActivity')?

Comment: In your project that class extending Activity and you had assigned layout xml(you have mentioned fragment tag ) file then follow all above instructions